# generate javascript object with some conditions

Tags: javascript

I have object like below.

```
{
    "lastViewTime": "May 09, 2013 08:36:09 PM GMT",
    "browser":
    {
        "Firefox": 200,
        "Others": 800,
        "Safari": 0,
        "Chrome": 522,
        "IE": 45
    }
}
```

from this I want to generate like below(I need to pass this in this manner only to some plugin the [] are important)

```
var browserData =  [
                        ['Firefox',  data.browser.Firefox],
                        ['IE',       data.browser.IE],
                        ['Safari',   data.browser.Safari],
                        ['Others',   data.browser.Others],
                        ['Chrome',   data.browser.Chrome]
                    ];
```

Now I want to add this key value pairs to  browserData only if data.browser.Firefox means those values are > 0.

for this I need to have a for loop . but i m not able to understand how I can make this kind of object. if I m making an array and pushing int to that key value pairs it is not giving me this kind of structure.

If some one can guide me in this it will be great.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's easier to help you fix something than it is to write something fresh for you.

Comment: var browserData=new Array();
    for (key in data.browser)
    {
     browserData[key]=data.browser[key];
    }
I was trying this kind of stuff but was not giving me proper result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var browserData = [];
for(var i in data.browser){
    if(data.browser.hasOwnProperty(i) {
        browserData.push([i, data.browser[i]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `if (data.browser.hasOwnProperty(i))` check. Sometimes it's necessary (ref: [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)).